# poll() return -1, but errno 0 in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

This program is proxy server.
I Used poll(). when receive the proxy request, I make two non-blocking sockets and connect and check the timeout.

when return -1 from poll(), after step3. (connect, errno==EINPROGRESS)
And This time, I checked in m_fds with gdb, it is normal.

How is this possible?
If it is possible, can I ignore this result?

This is a summary code of the flow.

```
int result = -1;
int timeout_ms = 500;
std::vector<struct pollfd> m_fds;
m_fds.reserve(1024);
std::map<int, Session> m_sessions;
std::set<Session> closeSessions;

while (!isStop) {
    result = poll(&m_fds[0], m_fds.size(), timeout_ms);
    // check connection timeout
    for(Session s : m_sessions) {
        if (s->isTimeout()) {
            closeSessions.insert(s);
        }
    }
    for (Sessions s: closeSession) {
        m_sessions.erase(s->getSocket());
        struct pollfd* pfd = findFdPtr(s->getSocket());
        close(s->getSocket());
        pfds->fd = -1;
    }
    closeSessions.clear();
    std::vector<pollfd>::iterator it;
    for (it = m_fds.begin(); it != m_fds.end();) {
        if (it->fd == -1) {
            m_fds.erase(it);
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
    // connect to proxy targets

    if (result < 0) {
        if (errno == EINTR) {
            continue;
        }
        // This break will stop the my program.
        // result < 0, errno == 0. what happen?
        printf("[errno:%d][err_msg:%s]\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        break;
    }

    if (result == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_fds.size(); i++) {
        // process something.
    }
}
```

And this is a proxy sequence. I skip writing exception.

Step.1) create non-blocking sockets.

```
int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int socket_option_value = 1;
if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &socket_option_value,
        sizeof(socket_option_value)) < 0) {
    close(sock);
    return -1;
}

if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &socket_option_value,
        sizeof(socket_option_value)) < 0) {
    close(sock);
    return -1;
}

int isNonblocking = 1;
if (ioctl(sock, FIONBIO, &isNonblocking) != 0) {
    return -1;
}
```

Step.2) register m_fds

```
struct pollfd serverFd;
serverFd.revents = 0;
serverFd.events = 0;
serverFd.fd = sock;
m_fds->push_back(serverFd);
```

Step.3) Try to connect

```
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(connectIp);
server_addr.sin_port = htons(connectPort);

int result = connect(m_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,
        sizeof(server_addr));

// trying...
if (errno == EINPROGRESS) {
    // register POLLOUT in m_fds. (ex: pfd.events |= POLLOUT;)
    return 0;
}

if (result < 0) {
    // unregister POLLOUT in m_fds. (ex: pfd.events &= ~POLLOUT;)
    return -1;
}

// unregister POLLOUT in m_fds.
// register POLLIN in m_fds.
```

Step.4) check connecting.

```
int result = -1;
int optval = -1;
socklen_t optlen = sizeof(optval);

do {
    if (getsockopt(m_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &optval, &optlen) < 0) {
        break;
    }

    if (optval != 0) {
        break;
    }

    result = 0;
}
while (false);

if (result < 0) {
    // remove pollfd in m_fds and close socket.
}
else {
    // unregister POLLOUT and register POLLIN
    // non-blocking -> blocking
    int isNonblocking = 0;
    ioctl(m_socket, FIONBIO, &isNonblocking) != 0) {
         // handling exception
    }
}
```

Update:
* how to process connection timeout.

I'm sorry my summarizing ability is not good.

Comment: Some poor practice here. After `connect()` it isn't valid to test `errno` before checking that the return value is -1. Your do/while loop testing SO_ERROR is also poorly coded: you don't need `do/while(false)` here. The final `ioctl()` block does not compile.

Comment: My psychic powers suggest that you have code that runs after the invocation of `poll` and it assumes that `errno` will not change.   I'm referring to specifically the code you have edited out and replaced with comments (`// check connection timeout` and   `// connect to proxy targets`)

Comment: You can't use `std::vector<struct pollfd>` in a C program!

Comment: @selbie: You might be right, but remember that nothing in the library sets `errno` to zero.  It would be interesting to know whether anything in the OP's code sets `errno` to zero.

Comment: I think you need to show a compilable MCVE ([MCVE]) that reproduces the problem.  There's too much missing that could be causing trouble.

Comment: Thank you for adding the extra code.  It isn't obvious (to me, at any rate) what's going on (that is, why it is going wrong).  I suggest capturing `errno` immediately after calling `poll()` — `int errnum = errno;` — and then checking whether `errnum` is zero when `result` is negative.  If `errnum` is zero, then it is close to being a bug; `poll()` shouldn't report failure and not set `errno`.  It is unlikely that's the problem, though.  This illustrates one of the problems with `errno` — it's a global variable that can be changed when you aren't expecting it to change.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried it the way you suggested, but I can not confirm it because the error situation is not reproduced. I did not consider `errno` is global variable.

Comment: You should save errno right after the operation `int err = errno` or something like that. errno is used by a bunch of routines and the C++ standard library calls the C standard library all the time.